# Docusign and service Authentication : invalid request

Tags: node.js, docusignapi, json-web-token

I am trying to use service authentication mechanism for logging in. But getting an invalid request.I have created the JWT using node jsonwebtoken package.below is the error I am getting.

**Copying the JWt creation logic**

```
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

var fs = require('fs');

//creating the payload for docusign

var payload = {
  "iss": "cb91877d-1d55-48ae-88d7-fd215c4fe2ca",
  "sub": "6cd4ea4e-3e68-4994-88b1-a321847cbf7e",
  "iat": 1508868716,
  "exp": 1508869916,
  "aud": "account-d.docusign.com",
  "scope": "signature",
    "nbf":1508868716, 
 "name": "neeush"
}

var cert = fs.readFileSync('private.pem');  // get private key

var token = jwt.sign(payload, cert, { algorithm: 'RS256'});
```

Can you find any issues in the same.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kReyy.jpg)

Comment: format the code before posting.

Comment: Do you have OrgAdmin feature enabled in your DS Account? and is above private.pem created by DocuSign?

Comment: No, I dont have OrgAdmin feature enabled.I have used user specific account.Regarding the Private key, yes it was generated using the DocuSign.I copied the private key and put the content in a text file and named it  "private.pem".

Comment: What "nbf":1508868716, 
 "name": "neeush" in this request, in DocuSign JWT there are no such fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var fs = require('fs');

//creating the payload for docusign
var payload = {
  "iss": "cb91877d-1d55-48ae-88d7-fd215c4fe2ca",
  "sub": "6cd4ea4e-3e68-4994-88b1-a321847cbf7e",
  "iat": 1509096042,
  "exp": 1509099042,
  "aud": "account-d.docusign.com",
  "scope": "signature impersonation",
  "name" :"name value" //not required
}

var cert = fs.readFileSync('private.pem');  // get private key
var token = jwt.sign(payload, cert, { algorithm: 'RS256'});
console.log(token)

console.log('---------------------------------------------------');
//printing the token to a file
fs.writeFile('jwttoken.txt', token, function (err) {
    if (err) 
        return console.log(err);

});
```

When the this generated token is used able to get post correct.
Earlier the token was printed on th console and copied from there which was creating the problem.
@Larry K Thanks for the help with the scope claim.

Answer (score 0):

Remove nbf and name claims.

Change scope claim to "signature impersonation"

See https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/oa2_jwt.html#creating-the-jwt-token

Comment: Hi Larry, I removed the nbf and name claims from payload.Also updated the scope claim as "signature impersonation".Bit it still is giving the same response.

Comment: Hi guys, I was able to  get the authentication done. Problem was due to fact that I was printing the token on the console and while copying there was new lines. When I am printing the same on to a file, I am able to login.Thanks for the help.I will post the working code below.